# How to retain form values after form submit through jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have form name as `myForm` with two elements dropdown and autocomplete() textbox. If an end-user selects the value on the dropdown and give a suggestions on the autocomplete (`tokens`) and click an apply button to get the search results matching our inputs.

My Screen Input : [HTML Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cMvwe.png)

My problem here is to retain the form values after submitting the form through jquery. My code is here:

```
$("#myForm").submit(function(){
    $('#myForm').attr("method","post");
    $('#myForm').attr('action','http://localhost:8080/LscaSearch/');
    $('#myForm').submit();
});
```

I wanted to retain the form values after submit the form. Any help on this?

Comment: You are using a normal post-back and not jQuery+Ajax (my bad, this is mad) :)... Forget retaining them client-side as the page is lost! They need to be returned from server-side (or switch to Ajax as Nikhil Talreja suggests).

Comment: does a custom object filled when formsubmit and fill its stringfied into a hidden field then retreive form items from this evaled stringfied object ??????

Comment: What is your server technology? PHP? .Net? most support hidden value passing and serializing custom controls.

Comment: my server technology is JAVA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use asynchronous form submission using jQuery AJAX. That way you can show the results on the same page without having to refresh it.

Comment: I think I preferred when you had jQueasy :)

Comment: You really need to show a practical example as I suspect they don't know where to start with Ajax (or they would already be using it!)